# Firebase Bulk json upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in Firebase.I haven't huge knowledge on the firebase.I want a bulk file uploader.

Suppose I have a file uploader in HTML.Using this a CSV/XML file will upload from a HTML.I convert this CSV/XML file in JSON(Array of JSON) then I want to upload this file in firebase.I have already converted and uploaded this file in firebase.But I face some problem, when file size is going big it takes too much time.

```
$rootScope.showLoader = true;
        usSpinnerService.spin('spinner-1');
        var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('Cars')
        var newItem = $firebaseObject(ref);
        var obj = {};
        var count = 0;

        for (var i = 0, len = jsonFile.length; i < len; i++) {
            newItem[jsonFile[i]["DealerID"]] = jsonFile[i];
            newItem.$save().then(function() {
                count++;
                if (count === (jsonFile.length - 1)) {
                    $rootScope.showLoader = false;
                    usSpinnerService.stop('spinner-1');
                    toastr.success('Successfully Upload this file');
                }
            })
        }
```

This is my code. I use here angularfire service for this.
Can anyone give example how I optimize the time? It will be helpful for me. I can't use any server here.

Comment: Define "too much time". Also: did you measure where the time goes? Is it client-code processing (which may be optimizable) or is it the upload itself (which is a fixed measure of the data size and bandwidth)?

Comment: For 2.6mb csv file it takes minimum 1 mintue to upload and it is client side code

Comment: And what's your bandwidth? A quick way to allow us to compare would be if you create a jsbin that reproduces the problem.